# Changing account email and logins on SE network

Tags: support, stack-exchange-openid, myopenid, my-logins

first, I read the threads and documentation about changing IDs. I may have miss something, for sure, but I read before posting.

I created my SE network login with my gmail address some years ago. Now, I'm trying to change the email address I use to connect SE. I also read, I can't remove the first email account to create my SE logins, ok.

I ran the procedure to add new login, and save the data to be widespread on the whole SE network. This seems to work because if I connect any category and click **Edit** -> **My logins**, I see:

> Stack Exchange
>    *my new email address* (with **change password** and **remove** actions)

But, I don't understand why I can't connect https://openid.stackexchange.com with my new credential, this leads to "No account found with this email address". Only the old address works.

Comment: This is by design, as Adam (the SE developer who works on the login system) explains in the dupe answer. (Unless I misunderstand your issue here, in which case please clarify and I'll retract my close vote)

Comment: Seems to be that...except I don't want to be logged in twice. So, another question (the last one I think): may I create a brand new SE account with my new email address and "attach" the child account to this new account?

Comment: Not sure, better ask Adam in a comment to his answer there